# Android PhoneGap localStorage via Lawnchair

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, lawnchair

So I've written an app using PhoneGap and Lawnchair. It works perfectly on iOS but on an Android device I get:

`sqlite returned: error code = 14`

This only happens on a device and not in the simulator, any points as to what I'm doing wrong?

Note: This stops Lawnchair calling any callbacks

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I'm running into the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I believe you need to specify an adapter for Android. gears-sqlite is listed for Android 2.x and above.

The project indicates: "by default, lawnchair will persist using dom storage but if other adapters are available and dom storage isn't supported by the currently executing javascript runtime. lawnchair will attempt each successive adapter until it finds one that works. easy. for example, a lawnchair built with the dom and gears adapters will gracefully degrade through all available android persistence solutions."

Current adapters for the project are found at: https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair/tree/master/src/adapters

See http://brian.io/lawnchair/ and http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

its ok. let that error come. wont affect the working of your app. :)

Comment: But it does, it breaks the Lawnchair callbacks don't fire :(

Comment: no the reason much be something else.  :|
i get this error everytime but lawnchair works fine